# How to match lines with only one tab in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a csv file. Some lines have 7 columns with tab delimited, and others have only one tab. I want to find all lines with only one tab and remove them.

What's the command to do this in VIM? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
[^\t]+\t[^\t]+
```

Comment: `+` is literal by default in vim

Comment: How to match multiple characters in which none of them are tab?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4116/regex-in-vi-how-does-one-use-character-classes-inside-groups-e-g-s-w

Comment: `^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*$` One tab for the entire line; the tab could be the 1st or the last character in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a single tab or more on every line, this will remove all lines without multiple tabs.

`:v/\t.*\t/d`

If you have lines with no tabs that you want to retain, this will not work as it will remove them.